# Get selected name tab in Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following html code which displays various pills and I want to retrieve the name of the selected one in Angular:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-5 justify-content-center" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="true">test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="false">test 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="false">test 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="false">test 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

is there a way to retrieve it please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngFor exactly for these situations,

```
  <ul *ngFor="let data of arrayOfData">
<li>
  <a>
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="false" (click)="liClicked(data)" >{{data}}</a>
  </a>
</li>
```

as you can see, the arrayOfData is the (test1' test2' test3 and so on..)

setting as a property in the ts file:

```
  arrayOfData = ['test1', 'test2','test3', 'test4']
```

and the function "liClicked" getting the value in the arrayOfData that clicked.
(the function sit in the ts file to: )

```
      arrayOfData = ['test1', 'test2','test3', 'test4']

      liClicked(selectedTest) {
        // Do your work here...
      }
```

Good Luck !

Comment: I actually needs it in my html code in another part where i need to pass it as a parameter